# Python to convert a CSV to multiple JSONS, one for each row

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I'm trying to use Python to convert a CSV into multiple JSON, one JSON for each row of the CSV.

I'm hoping to have the JSON filename be the data in the first column, and the JSON Content be the remaining columns.

So my CSV looks like this:

```
Filename, CustomerName, CustomerCode
Customer1.json,Customer1,C001
Customer2.json,Customer2,C002
```

And I'm trying to get two JSONs, one called Customer1.json and the contents of that to be Customer1, C001 (in JSON format).

I'm miles away from it right now but I have this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = csvfile.csv
for i in df.index:
    result = df.to_json(orient="split")
    parsed = json.loads(result)
    json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
    df.filename.to_json("row{}.json".format(i))
```

Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Can you include an example output file contents? Is the output a JSON list?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the rows. Set "Filename" as index so that the remaining row is the data you want in the json file, and convert each row to a list.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_csv("csvfile.csv", index_col="Filename")
for filename, value_series in df.iterrows():
    json.dump(value_series.to_list(), open(filename, "w"))
```

The first JSON file is

```
["Customer1", "C001"]
```

Comment: HI, thanks! I get : "TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable". I've tried changing to json.dumps(open(filename), value_series.to_list()) but then i get "TypeError: dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". Can you help ?

Comment: Fixed. I had the `dump` parameters in the wrong order.